# Facebook how to add screenshots images to app detail page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I create a facebook canvas app using java script sdk everything works fine but the problem is i am unable to add screen shots images only i add all other images like logo and banner images using my app details panel and these images display fine on app detial page but without screenshot images i can not submit my app to facebook app center. I read all the documents and search a lot for right solution but did not find how to add these images can anybody tell me how to add these and does facebook approve my app if i submit my app without these images.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add the images for app detail page:

https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/`<your app id>`/app-details/

Try to get high resolution images for best result.

[image]

Comment: i already use https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/<your app id>/app-details/ to add images but did not find any option to add screenshot images.Thanks

Comment: @user2423768, I added a screenshot. It's just below Banners in my app-details.

Comment: In my app detail page this option is not displaying is there any kind of setting or a specific platform or app category in which this option is displaying?

Comment: It's an app with actions, facebook login and facebook collection. I do not think that I did something special to get this options.

Comment: i got the issue to display this you have to select yes for website in App Center Listed Platforms.Thanks for you help

Comment: Cool - make a screenshot and post your answer. This might help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution you can display this option by just set website to yes in App Center Listed Platforms on your app detial page.